# Symfony2 bindRequset displaying property doesn't exist

Tags: php, symfony

I am new to Symfony and learning Symfony2 by creating a small project.

/******** UserType buildform function *******/

```
$age_choices = array('18'=>'18+','25'=>'25+','30'=>'30+','40'=>'40+','50'=>'50+');

$complextion_choices = array('Moderate'=>'Moderate','Fair'=>'Fair');

$builder
                ->add('first_name', 'text')
                ->add('last_name', 'text')
                ->add('email', 'text')
                ->add('phone', 'text', array('required' => false))
                ->add('age', 'choice', array('choices' => $age_choices) )
                ->add('complextion', 'choice', array('choices' => $complextion_choices) );
```

**/****** Creating user form *********/**

```
$user = new Users();

$form = $this->createForm(new UsersType());

return $this->render('TrytillUserBundle:User:signup.html.twig', array('form' => 
$form->createView()));
```

**Now When I submit this form.. getting it using following way.**

```
$user = new Users();

$form = $this->createForm(new UsersType(), $user);

$form->bindRequest($request);


if ($form->isValid()) {

   /// some task here.

}

return $this->render('TrytillUserBundle:User:signup.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView()));
```

The problem is that on bindRequest line it saying me that property first_name doesn't exist in Entity Users.

I have created Users Entity using doctrine and it's private $firstName in Entity/Users.php

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `->add('firstName', 'text')` instead of `->add('first_name', 'text')` in your `UserType::buildForm` function, same goes for `last_name`.

Comment: I had done that already but it wasn't working earlier... because I hadn't changed first_name to firstName in config/validation.yml